# jquery fullcalendar Callback is not defined error

Tags: php, jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have been following fullcalendar's docs and finally found a way to return json objects from my php backend database. But I'm getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not defined

Can anyone please help with this?

This is the bit of code for fullcalendar, mind you, I am using react. This executes in the ComponentDidMount bit as I saw in a tutorial for using fullcalendar.

```
$(calendar).fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'none',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next',
        },
    height: 480,
    width: 20,
    editable: true,
    eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element, view) {
            alert(event.title);
            var new_description =
           '<div style="background-color: #4286f4"><strong>Title: </strong><br/>' + event.title + '<br/>'+
           '<strong>Month: </strong><br/>'+view.title+'<br/></div>';
      return (new_description);
    },
    events: function(callback) {
         let d = $(calendar).fullCalendar('getDate');
         let month = moment(d).format("MM");
         let year = moment(d).format("YYYY");
         $.ajax({
           url: '/api/phpfile',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
             month: month,
             year: year,
           },
           success: function(doc) {
             var events = [];
             **$(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
              });**old code
              alert(doc[29].title);
              console.log(doc);
              events.push({
                  title: doc[0].title,
                  start: doc[0].start,
              })** new code
              callback(events);
           },
       });
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm still new to this stuff. Thank you.

UPDATE:

I tried changing the code to see what was showing, now I'm seeing more interesting behavior.It displays the title for the first month displayed (Current month), however by clicking next, it not only doesnt display the proper count in the next month, but the calendar freezes. It stops moving next or previous. What's going on???

Comment: You should indent your code properly (easier to actually see what's what) and also, your opening and ending brackets and parentheses doesn't seem to match in the posted snippet.

Comment: Done. They did match, I just didn't add the last two closing braces, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to this problem. 
For those who may need a solution to this or a similar issue, this is what worked, and it's really simple. This solves the problem for updating events across all/or some dates in your calendar.

```
$(calendar).fullCalendar({
    header: {
          left: 'none',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today prev,next',
    },
    height: 480,
    width: 20,
    editable: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        if(event.title == null){
          var new_description = '<div style="background-color: #d3d3d3;border-radius:10px;text-align:center;"><strong>Projects </strong><br/>0<br/>';
        }else{
          var new_description = '<div style="background-color: #fcd771;border-radius:10px;text-align:center;"><strong>Projects </strong><br/>' + event.title + '<br/>';
        }
        return (new_description);
    },
    events: function(start,end,timezone,callback) {
      let d = $(calendar).fullCalendar('getDate');
      let month = moment(d).format("MM");
      let year = moment(d).format("YYYY");
      $.ajax({
        url: '/api/phpfile',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          month: month,
          year: year,
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            for (var i=0;i<doc.length;i++){
              events.push({
                title: doc[i].title,
                start: doc[i].start,
              })//this is displaying!!!
            }
            callback(events);
        },
      });
    },
});
```

When I did a console.log on the doc, I found that this is literally the result json object from the backend. All you have to do is have a for loop go through the length of that object and push it into the events array, and execute  callback function of that array. You can render it in any way you like using eventRender. This was really really helpful.
The documentation is really poor in terms of helping solving problems like this because the code there does NOT explain syntax well and can send people new to this plugin flying off.

Answer (score 1):

```
events: function(callback)
```

is incorrect.

As per the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ the correct signature for the events function is:

```
function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
```

The first parameter, which you're naming "callback" is actually the start date of the current calendar view. Therefore calling it as a function won't work. There's also no need to do the work you're doing to work out the current start/end dates being displayed on the calendar - the start/end parameters which you'd ignored hand this to you on a plate.

Something like this should work much more smoothly:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
     let month = start.format("MM");
     let year = start.format("YYYY");
     $.ajax({
       url: '/api/phpfile',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {
         month: month,
         year: year,
       },
       success: function(eventData) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(eventData)); //just to give a visual on the data. From what you were doing in your example it looks like your data is already in a format suitable to be used by fullCalendar, so no need to push it all into another array
          callback(eventData);
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
       {
         alert("Error when fetching events: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
       }
   });
}
```

You could improve this still further, though. Your backend receives only a month and year. This is inflexible - if you amend it to accept two date variables called `start` and `end`, and return event data which falls between these dates, then you can use the much less verbose syntax provided by fullCalendar to automatically wire up to a JSON feed:

```
events: '/api/phpfile'
```

In this scenario FullCalendar will automatically send the "start" and "end" values as GET parameters to the endpoint URL. All your PHP has to do is read these variables and return the appropriate JSON. It'll also let you use views other than the "month" view, because you can return data for more specific time periods. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Update :
If you do a `console.log('end: ', end)`, you will see the following data:

```
end:  ƒ () {
            if (!isResolved) {
                isResolved = true;
                success.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        }
```

This is the callback function that returns the event data to the calendar.
My function looks like this :

```
 plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin],
            header: {
                left:  'prevYear,prev next,nextYear  today,   datePickerButton',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
            },
            defaultDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            editable: true,
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: (dates, callback) => {
                console.log('start: ', dates)
                console.log('callback: ', callback)
                axios.get('/training-session/auth/user').then(result => {
                    let events = []

                    result.data.forEach((event) => {
                        let date = event.date.split(' ')[0]
                        events.push({
                            title: event.name,
                            start: date + 'T' + event.time
                        })
                    })

                    callback(events)
                })
            }
```

And it is working!

Answer (score 1):

i encountered this problem and it was because of the version update. "callback" was renamed with the version 4 release.

old version was:

```
 function( startMoment, endMoment, timeZoneStr, callback )
```

and the updated version is:

```
function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback )
```

sample function:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: '/Calendar/GetCalendarData',  
    type: "GET",  
    dataType: "JSON",  
    success: function (result)  
    {  
       var events = [];  

       $.each(result, function (i, data)  
       {  
           events.push(  
           {  
               title: data.title,  
               start: data.startStr,
               end: data.endStr, 
               backgroundColor: "#9501fc"                   
           });                                  
       });  

       successCallback(events);
       //callback(events);  
   }  
});
```

and the reference for other changes and updates https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3