# Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function..... Setting the Events in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar

I am new in web development and trying to add a scheduler to my website.
I saw the FullCalendar that will help me achieve what I want,

But setting the events in the Calendar with Ajax has a problem,

That says, `Callback is not a function`,

This is the code I am working with:

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                url: '/Dashboard/getAllEvents',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'Post',
                success: function (doc) {
                var events = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
                        events.push({
                        id: doc[i].EventID,
                        title: doc[i].Title,
                        start: doc[i].StartDate,
                        end: doc[i].EndDate
                    });
                }
            callback(events);
        },
    });
},
```

I saw a bunched of solutions in this site, like this one;

[jquery fullcalendar Callback is not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437575/jquery-fullcalendar-callback-is-not-defined-error)

But it is not working as well, and display the error in the console.

How to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Read the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function and adjust your function parameters (and their usage) accordingly. It looks like you have used an example from somewhere for a much older version of fullCalendar. When something like that fails, the first thing to do is check the latest documentation!

Comment: @ADyson Hi, Thank you for responding on my questions, but How can I implement the link you said in view in MVC.

Comment: Huh? It's the same as what you're doing already except the function parameters have been updated. Nothing to do with MVC

Comment: @ADyson , I just did, but the events are not displayed. And also, the error in console is gone.

Comment: I.e. I'm saying look at the difference between `function (start, end, timezone, callback)` and what's in the documentation

Comment: Oops. It finally work. Thank you Adyson. maybe there is something wrong with the data I am processing. But it works fine now. Thank you again @ADyson.